# Mysql 5.7 st_distance_sphere return every time null

Tags: mysql, null, distance, latitude-longitude

this is my code:

```
SELECT st_distance_sphere( POINT(8,51) ,  point(@lon, @lat)) as distance FROM places;
```

If I execute it, all rows returns null.

Maybe the @lon @lat doesnt function? 
I don´t know...

If I replace the @lon @lat with for example 9 and 51 , it return '69976.54452205829' meters...

Comment: `@lon` and `@lat` are variables- do you define then anywhere before running the query?

Comment: so sorry... i have to remove the @ ... i dont no... suddenly it works fine.. 
I´ve tried this serveral times before.. this is strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for all: 
In my table there were two fields lat lon.

the right code is: `SELECT st_distance_sphere( POINT(8,51) ,  point(lon, lat)) as distance FROM places;`

Comment: What version of my sql are you using?

Comment: The sphere functions are availible for 5.7

Comment: it´s been a long time ago, but if I remember correctly, the laravel eloquent model havnt supported these. And secondly i wanted to be independent of some database exclusive functions, because, at that point in time, i wasnt too sure, which database system i would choose at the end.